# case_when fails (unexpected results) but conditions for case_when work outside

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to apply some equations to get the proportion of a line (numeric array) that coincides with another line (another numeric array). I have a data frame with the required values and I try to create a new column with the percentage outcome based on how the two lines coincide. I have checked the code (below) with some examples and it works OK, but when I apply the `case_when()` to the data frame, the output is not what it should be. I'll give you a basic example.

This is my output. It has a 'ID' column [char], a 'date' (days) column [dttm], a 'result' (value) column [double], 'difs' column is the number of days between the previous row [int], and 'Grp' column, that is a subgrouping value.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using. The idea is to get the previous value and calculate what % of the vector lies inside another vector whose limits are [2,3]. Right now I'm only checking if the conditions are right for every row. However, when it should get '0', get 'A', or sometimes 'Inf' when it should get 'A', etc, etc. I don't understand why. I think mutate iterate independently over every row inside the group, so I don't understand why the outcomes are wrong, compared to checking by hand.

```
Rsup = 3 # Highlimit of target array
Rinf = 2 # Low limit of target array

example_output = example%>% 
  arrange(id,Grp,day) %>% 
  group_by(id,Grp) %>% # Group by episodes (id + Grp)
  mutate(from_r = lag(result)) %>% # get previous result y(t-1)
  filter(difs != 0, difs < 181) %>% # dischard first sample of every subgroup/episode
  mutate( 
    p_days = case_when(
    (min(result,from_r) < Rinf) & (max(result,from_r) > Rsup) ~ 'A',  
    (min(result,from_r) > Rinf) & (max(result,from_r) < Rsup) ~ '100',
    (min(result,from_r) < Rinf) & (max(result,from_r) > Rinf) ~ 'Inf',
    (min(result,from_r) < Rsup) & (max(result,from_r) > Rsup) ~ 'Sup',
    TRUE ~ '0')
  )
# Case 'A':  check interval yt - yt-1 cuts target array for both limits
# Case '100': all the interval yt - yt-1 is inside target array (100%)
# Case 'Inf': interval cuts low limit of target array
# Case 'Sup': interval cuts high limit of target array
# Case True ~ '0': interval does not cut target array and it is not inside (0%)
```

This is how to create the basic example:

```
structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), day = structure(c(19104, 19105, 
19106, 19107, 19108, 19109, 19110, 19111, 19112, 19113, 19304, 
19305, 19306, 19307, 19604, 19605, 19606, 19607, 19608, 19609, 
19204, 19205, 19206, 19207, 19208, 19209, 19210, 19211, 19212, 
19213, 19214, 19215, 19216, 19217, 19218, 19219, 19220, 19221, 
19222, 19223), class = "Date"), result = c(1.55, 1.92, 3.6, 3.45, 
3.3, 3.46, 2.79, 2.55, 2.08, 2.27, 2.44, 4.59, 1.8, 0.75, 3.13, 
2.59, 2.16, 2.93, 1.38, 2.92, 3.19, 3.23, 3.48, 3.39, 2.62, 2.66, 
3.77, 3.44, 3.06, 2.59, 2.87, 1.97, 2.5, 2.84, 1.48, 3.04, 2.62, 
0.76, 2.74, 2.84), difs = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 191, 
1, 1, 1, 297, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c("A", "B"), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Of course, if someone knows a function to get the same output I'm trying with mutate + case_when, it will be very helpful too. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think mutate iterate independently over every row inside the group, so I don't understand why the outcomes are wrong. Maybe it mixes the results (and from_r) values of every group somehow?

Comment: Try with the vectorized `pmin/pmax` instead of `min/max`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? A tiny example would be wonderful. I never used those functions. @stefan

Comment: `pmin/pmax` compute the min and max of two vectors element- or rowwise, e.g. `min(c(1, 4), c(3, 3))` will give 1 (which is the overall min) while `pmin(c(1, 4), c(3, 3))` will give c(1, 3).

Comment: It's a good idea. However, I've seen it is dependent of the position of the elements and it would complicate more my code. It is not the same `pmin(c(1, 4), c(2, 5))` that `pmin(c(4, 1), c(2, 5))`. @stefan  The question is I know my lines inside `case_when()` work perfectly alone, but applied within the case_when they fail somehow. Thanks for your help

Comment: See my answer. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you use `min/max` instead of the vectorized `pmin/pmax`:

```r
library(dplyr)

ex1 <- example %>% 
  arrange(id,Grp,day) %>% 
  group_by(id,Grp) %>% # Group by episodes (id + Grp)
  mutate(from_r = lag(result)) %>% # get previous result y(t-1)
  filter(difs != 0, difs < 181) # dischard first sample of every subgroup/episode

ex1 %>%
  mutate( 
    p_days = case_when(
      (pmin(result,from_r) < Rinf) & (pmax(result,from_r) > Rsup) ~ 'A',  
      (pmin(result,from_r) > Rinf) & (pmax(result,from_r) < Rsup) ~ '100',
      (pmin(result,from_r) < Rinf) & (pmax(result,from_r) > Rinf) ~ 'Inf',
      (pmin(result,from_r) < Rsup) & (pmax(result,from_r) > Rsup) ~ 'Sup',
      TRUE ~ '0')
  )
#> # A tibble: 36 × 7
#> # Groups:   id, Grp [4]
#>    id    day        result  difs   Grp from_r p_days
#>    <chr> <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
#>  1 A     2022-04-23   1.92     1     1   1.55 0     
#>  2 A     2022-04-24   3.6      1     1   1.92 A     
#>  3 A     2022-04-25   3.45     1     1   3.6  0     
#>  4 A     2022-04-26   3.3      1     1   3.45 0     
#>  5 A     2022-04-27   3.46     1     1   3.3  0     
#>  6 A     2022-04-28   2.79     1     1   3.46 Sup   
#>  7 A     2022-04-29   2.55     1     1   2.79 100   
#>  8 A     2022-04-30   2.08     1     1   2.55 100   
#>  9 A     2022-05-01   2.27     1     1   2.08 100   
#> 10 A     2022-11-09   4.59     1     2   2.44 Sup   
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

To see the difference more clearly check:

```
min(ex1$result,ex1$from_r) < Rinf
#> [1] TRUE
pmin(ex1$result,ex1$from_r) < Rinf
#>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you see, using `min` the condition `min(ex1$result,ex1$from_r) < Rinf` gives `TRUE` for each row of your data. If you want to check conditions or set per row you have to use `pmin/pmax`.

Comment: Thanks. But my idea was to check row by row, I thought the `mutate(...)` part should iterate independently over every row, so `result` and `from_r` are unique values, not vectors? @stefan

Comment: I don't understand what makes the difference but this works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Yes and No. If you use a vectorized operation then yes. But min and max aren't vectorized. `result` and `from_r` are vectors. But as my example shows using `min/max` will not compute the min/max by comparing rows or elements from these vectors but will return the overall min/max.

Comment: Ok. That was my mistake, I thought result and from_r would be the unique value of every row, not the vector of all values. Cheers